# multiple certificates/vhosts with Express

Tags: node.js, express, https, virtualhost

I used nodejs for a while now with multiple hosts, using Express + vhost in Cody-CMS. Now I wanted to include also virtual https servers.

The SNICallback is called, but it ends there... my Express app "exp" is never called (not even if I replace it in createServer with a simple function -- in comments). I get the "request for: site1.com" (or site2.com), but nothing is returned to the browser.

For the http servers it works perfect.

Any help is welcome.

```
"use strict";

var express = require("express");
var vhost = require("vhost");
var fs = require("fs");


var app1 = express();
app1.all("/", function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World, site #1');
});

var app2 = express();
app2.all("/", function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World, site #2');
});


//////////////////
// certificates //
//////////////////
var crypto = require('crypto');

const site1 = {
  app: app1,
  context: crypto.createCredentials({
    key: fs.readFileSync('ws.key').toString(),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('ws.crt').toString()
  }).context

};
const site2 = {
  app: app2,
  context: crypto.createCredentials({
    key: fs.readFileSync('ws2.key').toString(),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('ws2.crt').toString()
  }).context
};

var sites = {
  "www.site1.com": site1,
  "site1.com": site1,

  "www.site2.com": site2,
  "site2.com": site2
};

// put (www.)site1/2.com in /etc/hosts to 127.0.0.1



//////////
// http //
//////////

var exp = express();
for (let s in sites) {
  console.log("http -> " + s);
  exp.use(vhost(s, sites[s].app));
}

exp.listen(80, function () {
   console.log("Listening https on port: 80")
});


///////////
// https //
///////////

var secureOpts = {
  SNICallback: function (domain) {
    console.log('request for: ', domain);
    return sites[domain].context;
  },
  key: fs.readFileSync('ws.key').toString(),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('ws.crt').toString()
};


var https = require('https');
var httpsServer = https.createServer(secureOpts, exp);
// var httpsServer = https.createServer(secureOpts, function(req, resp) { resp.send("hello"); });

httpsServer.listen(443, function () {
   console.log("Listening https on port: 443")
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SNICallback` has a second parameter: `cb`. `cb` has a signature of `(error, context)`. So your `secureOpts` should look like:

```
var secureOpts = {
  SNICallback: function(domain, cb) {
    console.log('request for: ', domain);
    cb(null, sites[domain].context);
  },
  key: fs.readFileSync('ws.key').toString(),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('ws.crt').toString()
};
```

Comment: Any advice what I should do when I receive a domain for which I don't have credentials?

Comment: You can probably pass an error object to `cb` for the first parameter instead of `null` as in the example.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of mscdex I made the example working.
http://coppieters.blogspot.be/2016/04/nodejs-virtual-hosts-websitesapps-on.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use also tls.createSecureContext withou crypto.createCreadentials

MY example here:

```
const https = require("https");
const tls = require("tls");

const certs = {
    "localhost": {
        key: "./certs/localhost.key",
        cert: "./certs/localhost.crt",
    },
    "example.com": {
        key: "./certs/example.key",
        cert: "./certs/example.cert",
        ca: "./certs/example.ca",
    },
} 

function getSecureContexts(certs) {

    if (!certs || Object.keys(certs).length === 0) {
      throw new Error("Any certificate wasn't found.");
    }

    const certsToReturn = {};

    for (const serverName of Object.keys(certs)) {
      const appCert = certs[serverName];

      certsToReturn[serverName] = tls.createSecureContext({
        key: fs.readFileSync(appCert.key),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(appCert.cert),
        // If the 'ca' option is not given, then node.js will use the default
        ca: appCert.ca ? sslCADecode(
          fs.readFileSync(appCert.ca, "utf8"),
        ) : null,
      });
    }

    return certsToReturn;
}

// if CA contains more certificates it will be parsed to array
function sslCADecode(source) {

    if (!source || typeof (source) !== "string") {
        return [];
    }

    return source.split(/-----END CERTIFICATE-----[\s\n]+-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/)
        .map((value, index: number, array) => {
        if (index) {
            value = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" + value;
        }
        if (index !== array.length - 1) {
            value = value + "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
        }
        value = value.replace(/^\n+/, "").replace(/\n+$/, "");
        return value;
    });
}

const secureContexts = getSecureContexts(certs)

const options = {
    // A function that will be called if the client supports SNI TLS extension.
    SNICallback: (servername, cb) => {

        const ctx = secureContexts[servername];

        if (!ctx) {
            log.debug(`Not found SSL certificate for host: ${servername}`);
        } else {
            log.debug(`SSL certificate has been found and assigned to ${servername}`);
        }

        if (cb) {
            cb(null, ctx);
        } else {
            return ctx;
        }
    },
};


var https = require('https');
var httpsServer = https.createServer(options, (req, res) => { console.log(res, req)});
httpsServer.listen(443, function () {
   console.log("Listening https on port: 443")
});
```

If you want test it:

1. edit /etc/hosts and add record `127.0.0.1 example.com`
2. open browser with url `https://example.com:443`